# Unable to sync Arduino Mega and RP4 using rosserial

Tags: ros, arduino, raspberrypi, encoder, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I know there has been many people posting about this issue, but I have tried all of the solutions I have seen so far and I am still unable to establish the connection. Here is the error message I am getting:

`Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino`

This is the compilation message I am getting:

`Sketch uses 11894 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes. Global variables use 1192 bytes (14%) of dynamic memory, leaving 7000 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.`

I am trying to publish encoder data from an Arduino Mega through rosserial. Here are some of the things I have tried so far: I have confirmed that this setup works with the rosserial examples. I have switched from odometry messages to Float32 since it seems that the size of these may cause the small memory of the Arduino board to overflow. I have confirmed that the baud rate in both Arduino and RPi are matching, I have tried increasing and lowering the baud rate, I have tried increasing and lowering the buffer size of `NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware>`, I have tried changing the cable and board, confirmed that the ports are connected and have sudo permission, and I have tried lowering and increasing the delay in loop(). I have also tried using ros launch to start the node, hard coding baud rate and buffer size in ros.h and ArduinoHardware.h, and trying to set the parameters from the terminal `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=115200`. No success...

This is what I currently have:

### encoder_data_publisher.ino

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>

ros::NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware, 10, 15, 128, 256> nh;
std_msgs::Float32 right_wheel_rpm_msg;
std_msgs::Float32 left_wheel_rpm_msg;

long publisher_timer;

    volatile int motor_right_input_A_count = 0; //if the interrupt will change this value, it must be volatile;
    volatile int motor_left_input_A_count = 0;
    
    const byte motor_right_input_A = 2;
    const byte motor_right_input_B = 3;
    const byte motor_left_input_A = 21;
    const byte motor_left_input_B = 20;
    
    float motor_cpr = 16.0;
    float right_motor_rpm;
    float left_motor_rpm;
    float right_wheel_rpm;
    float left_wheel_rpm;
    int gear_ratio = 270;
    
    // ROS publisher
    ros::Publisher right_wheel_msg_pub("right_wheel_rpm", &right_wheel_rpm_msg);
    ros::Publisher left_wheel_msg_pub("left_wheel_rpm", &left_wheel_rpm_msg);
    
    void setup() { 
      // ROS setup
      nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);
      nh.initNode();
      nh.advertise(right_wheel_msg_pub);
      nh.advertise(left_wheel_msg_pub);
      
      // Define the rotary encoder for right motor
      pinMode(motor_right_input_A, INPUT);
      pinMode(motor_right_input_B, INPUT);
      digitalWrite(motor_right_input_A, HIGH); 
      digitalWrite(motor_right_input_B, HIGH);
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(motor_right_input_A), motor_right_interruptCounter, RISING); 
    
      // Define the rotary encoder for left motor
      pinMode(motor_left_input_A, INPUT);
      pinMode(motor_left_input_B, INPUT);  
      digitalWrite(motor_left_input_A, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor_left_input_B, HIGH);
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(motor_left_input_A), motor_left_interruptCounter, RISING);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      motor_right_measureRPM();
      motor_left_measureRPM();
    
      right_wheel_rpm = right_motor_rpm / gear_ratio;
      left_wheel_rpm = left_motor_rpm / gear_ratio;
    
      right_wheel_rpm_msg.data = right_wheel_rpm;
      left_wheel_rpm_msg.data = left_wheel_rpm;
      
      right_wheel_msg_pub.publish(&right_wheel_rpm_msg);
      left_wheel_msg_pub.publish(&left_wheel_rpm_msg);
    
      nh.spinOnce();
      delay(1000);
    }
    
    void motor_right_interruptCounter()
    {
      motor_right_input_A_count++;
    }
    
    void motor_left_interruptCounter()
    {
      motor_left_input_A_count++;
    }
    
    void motor_right_measureRPM(){
      unsigned long start_time;
      unsigned long end_time;
      motor_right_input_A_count = 0;
      start_time = millis();
      
      while(motor_right_input_A_count < 101){
        continue;
      }
      
      end_time = millis();
      right_motor_rpm = 60000.0/(end_time - start_time)*motor_right_input_A_count / motor_cpr;
    }
    
    void motor_left_measureRPM(){
      unsigned long start_time;
      unsigned long end_time;
      motor_left_input_A_count = 0;
      start_time = millis();
      
      while(motor_left_input_A_count < 101){
        continue;
      }
      
      end_time = millis();
      left_motor_rpm = 60000.0/(end_time - start_time)*motor_left_input_A_count / motor_cpr;
    }
```

### rosserial_test.launch

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" name="rosserial_lipo" output="screen">
  <param name="~port" value="/dev/ttyACM0" />
  <param name="~baud" value="115200" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374873/unable-to-sync-arduino-mega-and-rp4-using-rosserial/) by [Sknet](https://answers.ros.org/users/72618/sknet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have experienced that re-creating `ros_lib` solved the corresponding error.

I suggest that you do `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .` with ROS running on RP4 and recreate `ros_lib`.

**Update:**

Thank you for trying my suggestion.
I read the source code.

```
  while(motor_right_input_A_count < 101){
    continue;
  }
```

The above is an infinite loop and it looks like it is not publishing.

```
void motor_right_interruptCounter()
{
  motor_right_input_A_count++;
}
```

is not running in parallel with `motor_right_measureRPM`.
( The same is  left side. )

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sknet](https://answers.ros.org/users/72618/sknet/) on 2021-04-03**:
Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. I tried removing and rebuilding the libraries with roscore running.

**Comment by [Sknet](https://answers.ros.org/users/72618/sknet/) on 2021-04-07**:
Yeap, that is correct. I was testing with the motor not moving so it was stuck in the while loop. Thank you!

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-08**:
I'm glad I could be of help.
If the problem has been solved, please click the correct button.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-09**:
Thank you.